# Get stock rotation of each product

Tags: stock

Is it possible to extract stock movement for each product between a time period, through a api call?

Comment: What is your Magento version?

Answer (score 0):

unfortunately, **no**. There is **no history of the stock**, or any "snapshots" of the product stock at any time.
**What you can do**, but this is **not 100% reliable** since the stock can be altered manually, is to get the current stock and subtract from it the quantity ordered since the day you want until now.

To get the qty ordered for a product you can try [this](https://magentofresher.wordpress.com/2013/08/11/magento-get-total-quantity-of-product-sold/) one, but you need to add the date filters by yourself.